# javax.mail.messaging exception connection time out error is thrown in jenkins when i try to use poll mailer plugin to read my inbox and triger a build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working on my client machine and a requirement is to trigger a jenkins build upon email subject. So i tried this using poll mailbox trigger plugin. To configure this, it needs host,username and pwd. When i test connection, i am getting

> javax.mail.messaging exception. connection timeout

I tried changing the host server address like `outlook.outlook365.com` `imap-mail.outlook.com` and `pop-mail.outlook.com` still getting same error

Expected should be:

> connection successfull

Actual:

> javax.mail.messaging exception. connection timeout

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Its a jenkins plugin and no much of code to show up. Host server name, username and pwd are parameters

Comment: The error i receive is "Connecting to the mailbox...
Error : javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection reset;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665) ". Now this is due to incorrect incoming server host name. I tried finding my incoming host server name for outlook in my system and the details are hidden. I tried using imap.**.***.dns.com and outlook.outlook365.**.***.dns.com. nothing worked. If i get exact incoming server, it wil work for sure.Can some one help me in gfetting @Akaisteph7

Comment: The error avax.mail.MessagingException: Connection reset; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665) " is now resolved by replacing the correct host name

Comment: I added markdown do emphasize the error messages and expectations, as well as the host addresses to make them easier to spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection reset; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665) " is now resolved by replacing the correct host name using mail.**.****-dns.com